# Calculate percent

Tags: java, integer, calculation

I was wondering how to calculate the percentage in a level system, let me explain better:
The user has his experience and this represents the level where the user is, i.e. if he has 0 experience he is level 1 and he needs 2000 experience for level 2.

Then I want to calculate the remaining percentage of how much is missing to reach 2000 experience.

Example:

```
int current_exp = 500;
int required_exp = 1500; // The remaining difference between the current experience and the required experience for level 2.
int level_two_experience = 2000;
float percent = ...
```

**I found an example on the internet where the user has 1,262 experience and needs 5000 for the next level so the percentage is 26.2%.**

Comment: Well then better ask the author. By my calculation, `1262 / 5000.0 = 0.2524`, i.e. 25.24%.

Comment: Need more input, how many level from 0 to 5000.

Comment: Assuming that you start from 0 experience on each subsequent level, just divide `current_experience` / `total_experience_to_level_up`. The result fraction is percentage.

Comment: Please, review your question. It sounds confuse to me. First you write "I want to calculate the remaining percentage", and then you write an exemple that seems current percentage, not remaining. Additionally your exemple does not match the calculation, as noticed by @Turing85

Comment: 26,2% would be the correct percentage if the prevous level was reached at 1000 XP and the next one is at 2000 XP.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation, I will try to improve next time! 
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing calculations with [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number), I would recommend to use double in case of Java.

If you need to be precise (for instance with money involved), I would handle the numbers after the decimal point myself.

In your case you could calculate it in the following way (remaining percentage):

```java
double percent = (level_two_experience - current_exp) / Double.valueOf(level_two_experience) * 100
```

If you want to calculate the percentage it currently has achieved it could be calculated this way:

```java
double percent = current_exp / Double.valueOf(level_two_experience) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
percentage_completed = current_exp / required_exp * 100

precentage_missing = (1 - current_exp / required_exp) * 100
```

Comment: This will not return the expected result. [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/gvKxpb)